# Flask function from class inheritance does not return correctly

Tags: python, flask

```
from app import app
import json
from flask.views import MethodView

from flask import request
from flask import url_for

from modules.auth import authenticate

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')


class Authentication(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        form_data = request.form
        if form_data.get('producer_apikey', None):
            self.producer_data = authenticate(
                form_data['producer_username'], form_data['producer_apikey'], form_data['region'])
        if form_data.get('consumer_apikey', None):
            self.consumer_data = authenticate(
                form_data['consumer_username'], form_data['consumer_apikey'], form_data['region'])

    def do_check(self):
         if self.producer_data.get("msg", None):
             return json.dumps
                 { "message" : self.producer_data["msg"] })
         if self.consumer_data.get("msg", None):
             return json.dumps(
                 { "message" : self.consumer_data["msg"] })



class ImageShareForm(MethodView, Authentication):
    def __init__(self):
        Authentication.__init__(self, request)

    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        self.do_check()




app.add_url_rule('/imageshareform', view_func=ImageShareForm.as_view('imageshareform'))
```

In the above code, when I run `self.do_check()` the condition does not return back to the browser. I would like to keep this function in class `Authentication()` because I will be reusing it a lot with class inheritance in other classes I will be writing.

Comment: What do you mean "the condition does not return back to the browser"?  Note that your `do_check` will return None if neither of the `if` conditions is met.

Comment: When I force the condition to be true, it does not return the json back to the browser. Only when I move the code under def do_check(self): the code returns to the browser properly. But not if the function is in class Authentication.

Comment: Is your code really indented like that?  The way you have it, `do_check` is inside `__init__` when it should just be outdented one more level (i.e., `def do_check` should be at the same indentation level as `def __init__`).

Comment: no, I modified it just for the post. I fixed the indentions.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `return` in your `post()` method?

Comment: not in the original code, but the point here is that when there is a return in the class Authentication(object): there is not return to the browser client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Python wants you to explicitly declare what you want to return:

```
def one():
    return 1

def two():
    return 2

def how_would_this_work():
    one()
    two()

how_would_this_work() # returns None

def this_works():
    one()
    return two()

this_works() # returns 2
```

You need to add an explicit `return` to your `post` method:

```
def post(self):
    return self.do_check()
```